# Return index of an array of tables

Tags: arrays, indexing, lua

I have the array:

```
racers = {}
racers[6] = {plCP = 4, plID= 21}
```

If I have the value plID=21, is there a way to return the index of racers? (In this case I'd like to return 6.)

I tried building a reverse index, but I'm only really able to get indexes within the table. Here's what I'm trying right now:

```
local index={}
for i = 1,5 do
    for k,v in pairs(racers[i]) do
       index[v]=k
    end
end
```

This returns "plID" when I pass the value 21, but I'd like it to return 6.

Answer (score 1):

For every racer in your list check wether the plID equals the id you are looking for.

```
local racers = {}
racers[1] = {plCP = 4, plID= 21}
racers[2] = {plCP = 2, plID= 4}
racers[3] = {plCP = 6, plID= 5}
racers[4] = {plCP = 222, plID= 7}
racers[5] = {plCP = 6, plID= 12}

function getRacerIndexById(racerList, id)
      for index, racer in ipairs(racerList) do
        if racer.plID == id then
          return index
        end
      end
    end

print(getRacerIndexById(racers, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
racers = {}
racers[1] = {plCP = 4, plID= 21}
racers[2] = {plCP = 2, plID= 4}
racers[3] = {plCP = 6, plID= 5}
racers[4] = {plCP = 222, plID= 7}
racers[5] = {plCP = 6, plID= 12}

local index={}
for i,d in pairs(racers) do
for k,v in pairs(racers[i]) do
   index[v]=i
end
end

return index[12]
```

This returns 5, which is the index of racers I was looking for.

Comment: Did you mean `index[d.plID] = i` ?

Comment: @Egor I went with `if k == "plID" then index[v]=i end` 
I imagine they do the same thing?

Comment: just because you get one number that looks right doesn't mean your solution is correct. switch racer 2 and 1 and then check index[4]. you'll get racer 2 with plID 21 instead or racer 1 with plID4... think about what you're doing in the inner for loop. you'r also using plCP values as keys for table index!!!

Comment: @Chase - Yes, this is a long route to the same result :-)

Comment: It's quicker and more efficient to do `for i, racer in pairs(racers) do index[racer.plID] = i end`. You don't have to loop through each field in the racer tables.